# Dependency errors for ks.h, ksmedia.h, and ksproxy.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, dependencies

I'm new to visual studio and I'm unsure how to link files.

I'm trying to create an application that tests camera property ranges  using ksproperties. Ex: To find out the range of exposure, zoom, and white balance a device supports.

Thus, I need to call Microsoft APIs such as 
KSPROPERTY_CAMERA_CONTROL_S and KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_EXPOSURE.

Here are my includes:

```
#include <ks.h>
#include <ksmedia.h>
#include <ksproxy.h>
```

And I've also tried them like this:

```
#include "ks.h"
#include "ksmedia.h"
#include "ksproxy.h"
```

But I'm still having dependency errors (4/82 errors):

```
Severity    Code    Description     
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PKSPROPERTY" is undefined       
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S" is undefined        
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PKSMETHOD" is undefined     
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "PKSEVENT" is undefined
```

These identifiers are located in files ks.h, ksmedia.h, and ksproxy.h and these files are in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\shared

Among other things I've tried, I've watched the below video to try to resolve the issues:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HExn9oTqdVo
Which instructs to go to the project's projects folder->C/C++ tab->General and add the above directory path to the additional include directories. As well as the Linker tab (within the project property's folder)->General and add the above directory path to the Additional Library Directories.

But the same errors persist. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. And coding in C++.

**UPDATE**
Trying @RbMn suggestion of adding #pragma message( message string ) I get the following output window. (**Note:** I commented out all the code that uses structs/variables from the ks.h, ksmedia.h, and ksproxy.h files to have a smaller output). In ksmedia.h I added `#pragma message("Testing at beginning of ksmedia.h")` in the beginning of the file and `#pragma message("After KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S struct")` right behind the KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_S struct.

The output shows that the second pragma message doesn't get reached:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CameraStarterKit, Configuration: Release ARM ------
1>exposure.cpp
1>Testing at beginning of ksmedia.h
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1205,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Window_Sample_Apps\Samples\CameraStarterKit\cpp\ARM\Release\CameraStarterKit\CameraStarterKit) does not match the .exe's OutputFile property value (Linker). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(C:\Window_Sample_Apps\Samples\CameraStarterKit\cpp\ARM\Release\CameraStarterKit\CameraStarterKit.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1205,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Window_Sample_Apps\Samples\CameraStarterKit\cpp\ARM\Release\CameraStarterKit\CameraStarterKit) does not match the .exe's OutputFile property value (Linker). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(C:\Window_Sample_Apps\Samples\CameraStarterKit\cpp\.exe.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1207,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(CameraStarterKit) does not match the 's OutputFile property value (Linker). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(CameraStarterKit.OutputFile).
1>CameraStarterKit.vcxproj -> C:\Window_Sample_Apps\Samples\CameraStarterKit\cpp\ARM\Release\CameraStarterKit\CameraStarterKit;.exe
1>Done building project "CameraStarterKit.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: visual studio here unrelated at all. are you `#include <ks.h>` ?

Comment: Yes, I've included ks.h, ksmedia.h, and ksproxy.h at the top of my .cpp file and it still isn't recognizing these external files

Comment: in project properties select Build 17134 as target

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's what I have. My target platform version is 10.17134.0

Comment: @RbMm forgot to tag you in my response

Comment: say `PKSPROPERTY` of course defined in `ks.h` and must be defined of course if you `#include <ks.h>`. for be sure add say `#pragma message( messagestring )` to ks.h (or make copy of ks.h and include copy instead original, for not temporary edit ks.h itself) before definition of `PKSPROPERTY` and in begin of file. make sure that correct version of ks.h (or it copy) included (use `/showIncludes` compiler option). in what problem research error ? and show direct compiler/linker error from output window (full text) but not what you show

Comment: Compiler errors have the format *Cxxxx*. The errors you posted aren't compiler errors.

Comment: @RbMm thanks. That helped me get a little closer. I updated and added the output window above. If you have any advice about the output let me know. Right now I'm going to troubleshoot with those warnings. I'll update if I get it

Comment: so move `#pragma message` inside header file for view where you breaked

Comment: `#pragma message` is in ksmedia.h header file twice @RbMm

Comment: `Testing at beginning of ` show that you include header file. but if you put another message near definition of `PKSPROPERTY` but compiler not show it - say that it probably in *#if*  block and compiler not go inside it (due some vars not defined, low version, or defined). move pragma message inside header file for found exactly reason. however this strange, say `PKSPROPERTY` must be unconditionally defined and so on

Comment: Yep @RbMm I added a couple more `#pragma messages` and found that the compiler doesn't enter this `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` to `#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */` because it is false.

Comment: how is `WINAPI_FAMILY` defined ? by default it defined to `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP`. but are you define it yourself ? can use next macros for check : `#define showmacro(x) __pragma(message(__FILE__ astring((__LINE__): \nmacro\t)#x" expand to\n" astring(x)))` `#define astring(x) _astring(x)` `#define _astring(x) #x` - `showmacro(WINAPI_FAMILY)` what show ? not 100 ?

Comment: You are compiling a C++/CX Windows Store app, not a regular C++ application (as your question tags imply). The error message is probably just a corollary of trying to access an API that cannot be accessed from a Windows Store application.

Comment: the user @IInspectable is right, your project is a store app, no desktop app. for Store apps, use the proper [UWP API for camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera)

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone! That makes sense. It looks like the UWP API for camera link will be just what I need!! @magicandre1981